# $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}\:\land\:\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow abc=n^3,\:n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are natural numbers such that $$\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca\in\mathbb{N},$$ prove that $abc$ is a perfect cube.

All I could get was $ab^2+bc^2+ca^2\equiv_{abc}0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Theorem** $\rm\displaystyle\ \ For\,\ a,b,c,n\in\Bbb Z\!:\ \frac{a}b+\frac{b}c+\frac{c}a =n\:\Rightarrow\: abc= m^3,\ $ for some $\rm\,m\in \Bbb Z$

**Proof** $\ $ Scaling by $\rm\,abc\,$ yields $\rm\quad  a^2 c + b^2 a + \color{#C00}{c^2 b}\, =\, nabc\qquad\qquad \color{brown}{(E)}$

We prove  $\rm\,\ a = kj^2/d^2,\, b = ik^2/d^2,\, c = ji^2/d^2,\,\ $ so $\rm\,\ {\bf abc = m^3}\:$ for $\rm\: m = ijk/d^2\in\Bbb Z,\: $

for $\rm\ i = (b,c),\ j = (a,c),\  k = (a,b),\  d = (a,b,c).\ $ Note $\rm\:d\mid i,j,k\: $ so $\rm\,d^2\!\mid jk,i^2,j^2,k^2.$

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm j^2 k\, 
&=&\ \ \ \rm (a,c)^2 (a,b)\\
&=&\ \ \ \rm (a^2,ac,c^2)(a,b)\\
&=&\,\rm a(a^2,ac,c^2,ab,cb,\ \ \ \color{#C00}{c^2b/a)}\ \ \ so,\ by\ \color{brown}{(E)}/a\\
&=&\,\rm a(a^2,\color{#e70}{ac},c^2, ab,\color{#0A0}{bc},\overbrace{n\color{#0A0}{bc}\!-\!\color{#e70}{ac}\!-\!b^2)}\\
&=&\,\rm a(a^2,ac,c^2,ab,bc,b^2)\\
&=&\,\rm a(a,b,c)^2 =\, ad^2\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Finally, by symmetry, also  $\rm\,\ ik^2 = bd^2,\,\ ji^2 = cd^2.\quad$ **QED**

**Remark** $ $ There is much literature on this equation, e.g. see [Dave Rusin's page](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/research-math/abcn/) and [OEIS A085705,](http://oeis.org/A085705) where you will find mention of the connection with elliptic curves.  Since the above proof uses only gcds, it holds true (mod units) over any gcd-domain, i.e. any domain where every pair of nonzero elements has a gcd. Hence this proof is more general than proofs employing prime factorization. For example, it works in the ring $\,\Bbb I\,$ of all agebraic integers, where no primes exist (since $\rm\, a = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{a}),\:$ but which, nevertheless, is a Bezout domain, so a gcd domain.

Answer (score 4):

For any prime $p$ and rational $x$, denote $v_p(x)$ (the $p$-valuation of $x$) the integer such that $x = p^{v_p(x)}a/b$ where $p$ doesn't divide $a$ nor $b$.
It is easy to show that $v_p(n) \ge 0$ if $n$ is an integer; $v_p(xy) = v_p(x)+v_p(y)$; and $v_p(x+y) \ge \min\{v_p(x), v_p(y)\}$, with an equality if those two valuations are distinct.

A number $x$ is a cube if and only if for every prime $p$, $v_p(x)$ is a multiple of $3$.
Let $p$ be any prime. We have to show that $v_p(abc) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

First, notice that $v_p(abc) \equiv v_p(\frac a b) - v_p(\frac b c) \pmod 3 (\equiv v_p(\frac b c) - v_p(\frac c a) \equiv v_p(\frac c a) - v_p(\frac a b))$

So if any two of the three valuations $v_p(\frac a b), v_p(\frac b c), v_p(\frac c a)$ are equal, we deduce that $v_p(abc)$ is a multiple of $3$.

Suppose that they are distinct. Then $0 \le v_p(\frac a b + \frac b c + \frac c a) = \min \{v_p(\frac a b), v_p(\frac b c), v_p(\frac c a)\}$ (because they are distinct).
And so $0 = v_p(1) = v_p(\frac a b) + v_p(\frac b c) + v_p(\frac c a) \ge 0+1+2 = 3 > 0$, which is impossible.

Comment: For the benefit of people who might come across this question and not know the definition of the $p$-adic valuation, it might be nice to add it?

Answer (score -1):

Consider polynom $(X-\frac a b)(X- \frac b c)(X - \frac c a)$.
It is equal to $X^3 - u*X^2 + v*X - 1$, where $u = \frac a b + \frac b c + \frac c a$.
and $v = \frac b a + \frac c b + \frac a c$.

for $X = 1$, you get $1 - u + v - 1 = v - u$. So you have $(1-\frac a b)(1- \frac b c)(1- \frac c a) = v-u$.

You can rewrite that: $(b-a)(c-b)(a-c)=c(b^2-a^2)+a(c^2-b^2)+b(a^2-c^2)$

but not sure it leads anywhere.

Comment: but $a/b + b/c + c/a$ is not the same as $b/a + c/b + a/c$.

Comment: mercio, you are right